# Tikz node background image not centered when using right= of

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, includegraphics

Why is the image not centered for the right node?

[image]

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mwe}
\tikzset{
  image/.style={
    path picture={
      \node at (path picture bounding box.center) {
        \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}};}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzstyle{node}=[rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, thick, draw =black!100, node distance = 16mm]

    \node[node, image] (y_src_i) [label=below:$\phi_i$] { };
    \node[node, image] (x_src_i) [right=of y_src_i, label=below:$\phi_j$] { };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You can either load the positioning library, as Marian G suggests, or use the correct syntax for positioning without that library: `right of=y_src_i,`. (Just in case you haven't read [esdd's comment below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447771/tikz-node-background-image-not-centered-when-using-right-of#comment1124996_447775).

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by that? I cannot see that comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need the `positioning` library. Secondly, you have to specify `anchor=center` in the `image`-style to achieve the desired effect.

***Code***

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{mwe}
\tikzset{
  image/.style={
    path picture={
      \node[anchor=center] at (path picture bounding box.center) {
        \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}};}},
  node/.style={
  rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, thick, draw =black!100, node distance = 26mm}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[node,image] (y_src_i) [label=below:$\phi_i$] {};
    \node[node,image] (x_src_i) [right=of y_src_i, label=below:$\phi_j$] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

***Output***
[image]

Comment: @esdd: You are right. Edited.

Comment: Can I conclude by your edit that `\tikzstyle{node}` should be defined in the document header?